# Password Reset token is returning null, although defined

Tags: meteor, user-accounts, meteor-useraccounts

I'm utilizing `useraccounts:unstyled`, `accounts-base`, `accounts-password` and trying to implement a password resetting feature.

I have my route defined as such:

```
FlowRouter.route('/reset-password/:token',  {
  name: 'reset-password',
  onBeforeAction: function()
    Accounts._resetPasswordToken = this.params.token;
    this.next();
  },
  action(params){
    Accounts._resetPasswordToken = params.token;
    mount(MainLayout, {
        content: (<ForgotPassword />)
    });
  }
});
```

My template defined as such:

```
<template name="ForgotPasswordModal">
  {{#if $not currentUser}}
    <div class="forgot-modal {{$.Session.get 'nav-toggle'}}" id="{{checkState}}">
        <i class="fa fa-close resetPwd"></i>
        {{> atForm}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

And my helper functions defined as:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.ForgotPasswordModal.onCreated(function(){
    if(Accounts._resetPasswordToken){
      Session.set('resetPasswordToken', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
    }else{
      console.log("else");
    }
  });

  Template.ForgotPasswordModal.helpers({
      checkState() {
          return (AccountsTemplates.getState() == 'resetPwd') ? 'forgot-modal' : '';
      }
  });

  Template.ForgotPasswordModal.events({
    "submit .at-btn": (event)=>{
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event);
      password = document.getElementById('reset-password-new-password').value;
      console.log("password", password);
      if(password){
        Accounts.resetPassword(Session.get('resetPasswordToken'), password, (error)=>{
          if(error){
            console.log("error: ", error);
          }else{
            console.log("success");
            Session.set('resetPasswordToken', null);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Upon clicking submit I get `Error: Match error: Expected string, got null (unknown)`.

Although if I load the route up (with a valid token) and run `Session.get('resetPasswordToken')` the token is returned validly.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this for a few days, couldn't figure it out... then after some rearrangement it finally worked.

And you don't have to use Meteor's default route & form for resetting the password.

You're close @Sleep Deprived Bulbasaur, your route should look like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/reset-password/:token',  {
  name: 'reset-password',
  action(params){
    Session.set('_resetPasswordToken', params.token);
    mount(MainLayout, {
        content: (<ForgotPassword />)
    });
  }
});
```

I did not need the onBeforeAction, Accounts._resetPasswordToken, or this.next(), and it works just fine and logs you in automatically.

Your template should have something like this:

```
if (!validateForm(password,passwordAgain)) {
  console.log('Your passwords dont match');
} else if (!isValidPassword(password, passwordAgain)) {
  console.log('You do not have valid passwords');
} else {
  let token = Session.get('_resetPasswordToken');
  Accounts.resetPassword(token, password, function(err) {
    check(token, String);
    if (err) {
      console.log('We are sorry but something went wrong.');
    } else {
      console.log('Your password has been changed. Welcome back!');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this way:
FlowRouter.route('/#/reset-password/:token');
This is default route for reset Password.